# Conditional probability of destroying the target

Tags: probability

Assume that probability of hitting the target in one shot is $p$, while the probability of destroying the target given $k ≥ 1$ hits is equal to $1 − q^k$ .
What is the probability of destroying the target, if $n$ shots was fired?

For $n=1$ the answer is obvious $p(1-q)$. For $n$ greater that $1$ I am not sure if my solution is correct:
$$(1-q^n)p^n+(1-q^{n-1})p^{n-1}(1-p){n-1\choose n-2}+(1-q^{n-2})p^{n-2}(1-p)^2{n-1\choose n-3}+...+(1-q^2)p^2(1-p)^{n-2}{n-1\choose 1}+(1-q)p(1-p)^{n-1}$$

Can anyone check if this is correct? Since this formula is not user friendly is it any simpler solution to this problem?

Comment: Your formula definitely makes sense, but seem to need some correction: namely, the coefficient of $(1-q^k)p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ should be $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, if all $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ are replaced by $\binom{n}k$, but the way it is written makes it hard to understand. Let us find the probability that the target is not destroyed after $n$ shots. If $X$ denotes the number of hitting the target, then
$$\require{cancel}\begin{align*}
\Bbb P(\text{not destroyed}\mid n \text{ fires})&=\sum_{i=0}^n\Bbb P(\text{not destroyed}, X=i\mid n \text{ fires})\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n\Bbb P(\text{not destroyed}\mid X=i,\cancel{n \text{ fires}})\Bbb P(X=i\mid n \text{ fires})
\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n q^i\binom{n}ip^i(1-p)^{n-i}\\&=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}i(pq)^i(1-p)^{n-i}\\&=(1-p+pq)^n
\end{align*}$$ by binomial theorem. So it follows
$$
\Bbb P(\text{destroyed}\mid n \text{ fires})=1-\Bbb P(\text{not destroyed}\mid n \text{ fires})=1-(1-p+pq)^n.
$$

Comment: Excellent solution, thank you very much

Comment: @yzaneksa After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, please [consider "accept" the answer](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4945/290189) by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](//math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).